# Separar cadena en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Si tengo una cadena de texto tal que así:

```
var cadena1 = "cadena_1";
```

Y solo necesito obtener el 1 de la cadena anterior para meterlo en una variable, como puedo hacero?

Haciendo esto:

```
var res = cadena1.split("_");
```

el resultado es `cadena,1`

Comment: tu asignacion no sería un `var cadena1 = "cadena_1";`?

Comment: Si, una errata.

Comment: La función split es de javascript solo y retorna un arreglo. si deseas obtener el 1 solo, basta con que accedas a la posición del arreglo, en ese caso seria res[1].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

bastaría con hacer:

```
var res = cadena1.split('_')[1]; // segundo elemento del array que se obtiene al hacer split
```

saludos

Answer (score 8):

Puedes usar [`split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t5az126b(v=vs.94).aspx) cogiendo el segundo elemento:

```js
var cadena1 = "cadena_1";
var res = cadena1.split("_")[1];
console.log(res);
```

O usar [`substring()`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en//SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_standard_string_substring_r.html) si sabes que solo va a haber 1 numero. Con la posibilidad de valores `> 9` usaría la opción de `split()`

```js
var cadena1 = "cadena_1";
var res = cadena1.substring(cadena1.length-1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Solo usa [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var tmp = cadena1.split("_"); //retorna un array
//console.log(tmp);
var num = tmp[1];
console.log(num);
```